# Foreign Key relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework. I have two tables...

```
public class S7_Baskets
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string S7_BasketID { get; set; }
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int S7_Seqno { get; set; }
    public int S7_ProductID { get; set; }

    public virtual S2_Products S2_Product { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class S2_Products
{
    [Key]
    public int S2_ProductID { get; set; }
    public string S2_Desc { get; set; }
}
```

The S7_ProductID should refer to the S2_ProductID?

Comment: This is a question that is purely about Entity Framework code-first.  It has nothing what at all to do with MVC3.  The fact that you are using it in an MVC3 project is irrelevant.

Comment: I think that's what the virtual property you defined in the entity will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question and what you are tryiing to do.  I think you want to add the ForiegnKey attribute to the S7_ProductID property.

As shown here:

```
public class S7_Baskets
{
   [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   [Column(Order = 0)]
   public string S7_BasketID { get; set; }

   [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   [Column(Order = 1)]
   public int S7_Seqno { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("S2_Products")]
   public int S7_ProductID { get; set; }
   public virtual S2_Products S2_Product { get; set; }
```

}

You might also need to add something like the following in the OnModelChange method of the model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<S7_Baskets>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.S2_Products)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.S7_ProductID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Thanks it was  [ForeignKey("S2_Product")] not  [ForeignKey("S2_Products")] no 's' i think it worked!

Comment: Try changing the attribute to [ForiegnKey("S2_Product")] to match the property name rather than the entity name.

Comment: Oops.  I didn't see you last comment as I was entering mine.